# Handle api response using sealed class in rxjava

Tags: android, retrofit2, rx-java, rx-android, sealed-class

> I want to handle api response using sealed class

```
sealed class Result<out T> {

    data class Success<out T>(val value: T) : Result<T>()
    data class Failure<out T>(val throwable: Throwable) : Result<T>()
}
```

My api is working properly for

```
@POST("/api/doctor_app/UpdateProfile")
fun UpdateProfile(@Body request: Doctor): Single<GenericResponse>
```

and when I updated my api to

```
@POST("/api/doctor_app/UpdateProfile")
fun UpdateProfile(@Body request: Doctor): Single<Result<GenericResponse>>
```

**Failed to invoke private com.utils.Result() with no args**

How can I achieve response like

```
configService.UpdateProfile(doctor)
            .subscribeOnIO()
            .map {
                when(it){
                    is Result.Success -> Result.Success(it.value)
                    is Result.Failure -> Result.Failure<GenericResponse>(it.throwable)
                }
            }
```

where **subscribeOnIO**

```
fun <T> Single<T>.subscribeOnIO(): Single<T> {
    return this.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
}
```

Comment: Have you solved it? I am facing the same issue

Answer (score 0):

did you try something like this:

```
@POST("/api/doctor_app/UpdateProfile")
fun UpdateProfile(@Body request: Doctor): Single<Result.Success<GenericResponse>>
```

and then

```
configService.UpdateProfile(doctor)
        .onErrorReturn { Result.Failure(it) }
        .subscribeOnIO()
        .map {
            when(it){
                is Result.Success -> Result.Success(it.value)
                is Result.Failure -> Result.Failure<GenericResponse>(it.throwable)
            }
        }
```

Comment: why you are returing Result.Success in UpdateProfie

Comment: it's like "Expected result". and if there is  an error you map it into `Result.Failure`

Comment: I am talking about Single<Result.Success<GenericResponse>>

Comment: yeah, i got. `Single<Result.Success<GenericResponse>>` is your expected result. Something you'd like to get from the request. And if there is any error you map it into `Result.Failure`

Comment: @borichellow I have followed the same approach but i am always getting this exception, java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to invoke private Result() with no args

Comment: @OmarHassan my approach isn't correct. Result should be handle at repository level. Read Uncle Bob Clean architecture